# dwm freezes, disabling keyboard, mouse click, and making screen blink

Tags: debian, freeze, window-manager, dwm

I'm using (unpatched) `dwm` inside a VM with a Thinkpad P50 and it freezes/crash randomly. When it happens, I'm still able to move the cursor (but cannot click), and the keyboard is frozen, repeating the last key (if it crashes when I'm typing). I'm unable to exit dwm nor press any keyboard shortcut. The issue can happen once every 2 days as every 10 minutes.

`dwm` has been downloaded using `git`, using the last commit available on the master branch ([9f8855343c881bdc01b9fff5b956537ba1106b76](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/commit/9f8855343c881bdc01b9fff5b956537ba1106b76.html)). The only modification I've made was changing the keys to works with french keyboards and set `urxvt` as `termcmd`. I'm also using `dmenu`.

It's launched using `startx`, with the following `.xinitrc`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while xsetroot -name "`date` `uptime | sed 's/.*,//'`"
do
  sleep 1
done &

xrdb -merge "$HOME/.Xresources" &

exec dwm
```

Being not sure how to debug this, could you help me looking at the relevant logs ?

I've tried to change graphics settings in the BIOS (Discrete to Hybrid) without any effects. Other posts online presents similar issues but seems too specific to be reproduced.